# How can I set the default value for a custom "Number" field in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss, content-type

I created a custom field for a content type I am creating using the XML below.

```
<Field ID="{GUID}" Required="False" DisplayName="Likes" Name="Likes" Type="Number" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"><Default>0</Default></Field>
```

The field is meant to be used as a counter of sorts, and will be incremented programmatically.  But, I can't get the value to default to "0" when a new item is created.  However, for some reason, when I create a new column manually using the Site Collection settings page and configure it to default to "0" it works as it should.

So far, I've tried the following tactics:

- I removed the "default" element from the field definition, and set the "DefaultValue" attribute on the content type definition.
- I exported a definition for the manually-created, working column (using an Imtech STSADM tool).  Then, I added it to my field definitions XML and modified the IDs so that I could add it to my content type.  When I did this, it **still** didn't work, even though it was exported from a working column!

Any idea why this isn't working for me?

Comment: This is being used in a "Pages" list on a publishing site.  If I add the offending column to a standard list, the default value works as expected.  Do I need to define default values differently for lists like "Pages"?

Comment: I've noticed this behavior on the pages library as well. I'm investigating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this issue was that my custom content type (the one that contained the number field) was not set as the default content type for the Pages list.  I was most likely creating page items using a different content type, accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

Other than case (it's [Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415119.aspx), not default), it looks good to me. Also, maybe you could try Integer or Counter for Type instead of Number.

Comment: Right, sorry about the case, I re-typed it by hand since my development actually occurs on another machine without Internet access.  I'll update the example.